# USB endoscope camera

Tags: usb, webcam

I think a USB endoscope/inspection camera could be useful, for looking in small spaces. It seems there's loads of these available cheaply, eg on Ebay, or Amazon, or Gearbest etc, for under $10.

But which ones are any good?

I would like to connect it to my phone or tablet (Android), so would need a Micro USB connection. Would be useful if it also had an adapter for regular USB. Presumably they require their own app/software.

Is there much difference in image quality between them? I'm not expecting high resolution, just good enough to see what's there.

It would need a cable a couple of metres long, and some sort of LED lighting on the end. And preferably water resistant.

Comment: It is software that is the problem, since the shop cost of the hardware is trivial. Cheap devices may come with indifferent software. I bought a cheap USB microscope. The hardware was adequate, but the software CD was full of malware.

Comment: Did you inform the supplier?